# angular2 display message if field value is invalid

Tags: angular

I have the following field in an angular2 page (I am not using forms).

```
<input id="firstname" name="firstname" class="field-input field-validation-input" [(ngModel)]="firstname"
                    placeholder="First name" spellcheck="false" required #firstNameField>
```

Now I want to display a message at the bottom of the field if it is invalid, in this scenario if it is empty.  What is the best way to do this, I can use firstNameField.className but as you can see there are a number of classes here and trying to filter for ng-invalid might be a problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```
#firstNameField="ngModel"
```

so that this template variable references the [NgModel](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel) directive, and thus have access to all its properties and methods:

```
<div *ngIf="!firstNameField.valid">Houston, we have a problem</div>
```

or

```
<div *ngIf="firstNameField.hasError('required')">The first name is required</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a form and Angular's built in validation features?

Without forms, you could write some code in the setter for the firstname field that performs the validation and sets the message. You could then add the elements to display the message if the message is set.

In the component:

```
   message: string;
   _firstName: string;
   get firstName(): string {
      return this._firstName;
   }
   set firstName(value: string) {
      this._firstName = value;
      // Validation here
      // If validation does not pass
      {
         message = "Please enter a valid value";
      }
   }
```